# Function whose limit does not exist at all points

Tags: calculus, limits, real-numbers

There are functions which are discontinuous everywhere and there are functions which are not differentiable anywhere, but are there functions with domain $\mathbb{R}$ (or "most" of it) whose limit does not exist at every point? For example, $ f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{N}, f(x) = $ {last digit of the decimal representation of $x$}. Is this even a valid function?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ otherwise has no limits

Comment: @moni94 Your function definition is not valid because the "last digit of the decimal representation" is not defined for every real number. (Take $1/7$ for example.)

Comment: I believe $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ has a limit at every irrational number, no?

Comment: No, it doesn't. (With $f(x)=0$ at every irrational.)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational and $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational. Let's prove it doesn't have a limit at any point. Let $y\in \mathbb{R}$, suppose $y$ is irrational and that there exists $L$ the limit of $f$ at $y$. Then given any $\epsilon<1/2$, there is $\delta>0$, such that $x\in (y-\delta, y+\delta)\setminus\{y\}$ implies $|f(x)-L|<1/2$. Now, since there exists $x_0,x_1\in (y-\delta, y+\delta)\setminus\{y\}$ such that $x_0$ is rational and $x_1$ is irrational we get that $1=|1-0|=|f(x_0)-f(x_1)|\leq |f(x_0)-L|+|f(x_1)-L|<1/2+1/2=1$, a contradiction. So the limit at any irrational $y$ does not exists. The same argument applies to any rational $y$, so the limit doesn't exists at every point.

Answer (score 1):

Things can get wild: There are functions $f:\mathbb {R}\to \mathbb {R}$ such that for every interval $I$ of positive length, $f(I) = \mathbb {R}.$

Answer (score -1):

Now f(x) is define f:R→R by f(x)=x if x is rational and f(x)=-x if x is irrational. How to prove it limt (x approach to a) f(x) doesn't exist at a belongs to R with a not equal to 0.

Here limit doesn't go to constant value. How to prove it by using above theory.